# PowerShell - Filter results by values from array

Tags: arrays, sharepoint-2010, filtering, powershell-2.0

I'm writing a script to list the properties of SharePoint groups.
This piece of code works fine but returns all Sharepoint groups from `$site`, meaning hundreds of records.

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://MyWeb/MySiteCollection
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups
foreach ($grp in $groups) { do something }
```

So I was looking to filter the list of groups; and I came up with this other piece of code, which also works.

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://MyWeb/MySiteCollection
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups | ? {$_.Name -like "Training*"}
foreach ($grp in $groups) { do something }
```

Then I thought, why not storing the names of the groups I'm interesting in an array and select from `$groups` only the ones where the group name matches one of the names in my array.

So I created a file named 'Groups.ini' and typed the names of the groups I'm interested in.
I wrote this script, but it doesn't work

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://MyWeb/MySiteCollection
$mygroups = Get-Content D:\Tools\Groups.ini
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups | ? {$_.Name -like $mygroups}
foreach ($grp in $groups) { do something }
```

The line I'm interested in is

```
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups | ? {$_.Name -like $mygroups}
```

How can I select the items from `$groups` where the name is one of the value of my array `$mygroups` ?

Comment: I posted this question on the Microsoft forum instead, should anyone be interested to follow it up : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/38600bd4-a0c1-4981-bbea-6da79d8b539b